# Android SVG Animation draw half image only

Tags: android, animation, svg

Currently I am working on android application. that contains An SVG image. 
I used [this SVG animated library](https://github.com/jrummyapps/AnimatedSvgView) to draw svg paths with animation.
but it only draws **half** the image not the whole image.  See [this example screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1dfi.png).

Could anyone help with this problem?

Comment: It could be a number of things.  Post more information.  For example, the SVG, and the attribute values you've used in your layout for `AnimatedSvgView>`.

Comment: <com.jrummyapps.android.widget.AnimatedSvgView
        android:id="@+id/iv_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        app:animatedSvgFillStart="3000"
        app:animatedSvgFillTime="2000"
        app:animatedSvgTraceMarkerLength="5"

        app:animatedSvgTraceTime="5000"
        app:animatedSvgTraceTimePerGlyph="3500" /> @PaulLeBeau

Comment: Put it in your question so it is readable :)  Your SVG is also important so we can see its width, height and viewBox values.